# PHP and File handling process to record visitor ips and banned them

Tags: php, file-handling

i would like to record the visitor ips in a file. then after second attempt to visit, i dont want that person to visit that website within 10 days. If he visits again then i want banned message to be produced. i can do this with mysql database but i want to do through file handling. Its urgent

Answer (score 0):

I think following code snippet will be helpfull for you:

```
define('IP_FILE', 'ip.php');//where to save IP data
define('LIMIT_SECONDS', 10*24*3600); // 10 days
//loading IP data
function loadIPFile() {
    if (file_exists(IP_FILE)) {
       require_once IP_FILE;
       if (isset($ipArray) and is_array($ipArray)) {
            return $ipArray;
        }
    }
    return array();
}

//saving IP data
function saveIPFile($ipArray) {
    $fp = fopen(IP_FILE, 'wb');
    fwrite($fp, '<?php'.PHP_EOL);
    fwrite($fp, '$ipArray = '.var_export($ipArray, true).';'.PHP_EOL);
    fwrite($fp, '?>');
    fclose($fp);
}

$ipArray = loadIPFile();//load info into array
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];//visitor ip
//if such ip already exists and 10 days are not behind us redirect visitor
if (isset($ipArray[$ip]) and time() - $ipArray[$ip] < LIMIT_SECONDS) {
   header('Location: banned_page.php');
   exit;
}
else {
    //else record new  ip or new time
    $ipArray[$ip] = $time;
}
//save IP information
saveIPFile($ipArray);
```

Comment: Undefined variable: time in index.php on line 32

Answer (score -1):

If you know how to do this with the database, why do you want to do it with a file? A database is basically a file with functionality sitting on top to help you access the data. By using files to directly to store this sort of data you are having to rewrite the minimal access functionality that comes out of the box with MySQL. Why reinvent the wheel?

If for some reason you don't have access to MySQL, then perhaps try SQLite http://php.net/manual/en/book.sqlite.php, gives you a lot of sql type functionality, but based on a file in your local directory rather than sql server.